# How to specify which Perl bin to use

Tags: windows, perl, environment-variables

I have multiple versions of Perl on my Windows pc.

Here's the version I want to use when I type `perl program.pl` ... `C:\Perl64\bin`

Do I use `#!`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shebang is used by Unix kernels to invoke the correct interpreter. As Windows is not unixoid, the shebang is generally useless (however, perl itself will parse the shebang for flags like `-w` or `-T`).

In contrast, the `PATH` variable is common accross all modern platforms. It specifies all locations where executable files may reside. The *first* match is used, i.e. you can override a default by prepending a specific location.

On Windows, the dirs are seperated by `;`, whereas Unix uses `:`.

On the `cmd.exe` shell, you can modify the path like

```
set PATH=C:\Perl64\bin;$PATH
```

if I am not mistaken (have nothing to test it at hand). It can also be modified under the advanced system settings. Look for “Environment Variables”.

Comment: Windows uses file associations instead of the shebang. You can adjust the file associations for .pl files using command-line tools `assoc` and `ftype`. Do a search for those in conjunction with "Perl" should find the exact usage.

Comment: @ikegami I read the question as OP wanting to change the program which is executed on typing `perl` into the command line. The `.pl` file would just be an argument in that case. (For every other usage, changing the association is the correct course of action)

Comment: If that's the view you're taking, then you were mistaken when you said the shebang caused the correct interpreter to be invoked in unix systems, because `perl file` overrides the shebang just as it does file extensions. Anyway, you're being way too literal. If he can get `program.pl` (rather than `perl program.pl`) to run the correct Perl, I'm sure he'd be happy too.

Comment: Set the path in Windows correctly: `set "PATH=C:\Perl64\bin;%PATH%"`